# Blowfish crypt(3) equivalent using OpenSSL?

Tags: c, hash, openssl, blowfish, crypt

I am trying to generate a one way password hash (Blowfish) in C using `crypt` library. However, the return hash is null for some reason.

```
/*
gcc  -lcrypt   crypt.c -o crypt
./crypt
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char *hash= crypt("root", "$2a$10$vI8aWBnW3fID.ZQ4/zo1G.q1lRps.9cGLcZEiGDMVr5yUP1KUOYTa");
  printf("hashed=%s\n", hash);
  return 0;
}
```

How can i accomplish the same thing using OpenSSL library?

Comment: What does your compiler say? You did enable warnings, didn't you?

Comment: @turbulencetoo well if i change the $id$ from 2a to 1 it return a hash

Comment: @PascalCuoq no warnings or anything.

Comment: The man page for `crypt(3)` on Linux (an Ubuntu 14.04 derivative) discusses the choice of algorithm using `$id$` and notes that the ID: `2a | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some Linux distributions)`.  This suggests that your distribution isn't one of those that has added Blowfish support.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok, How can i accomplish the same thing using OpenSSL library?

Comment: Short answer: I don't know.  It would probably be easier to take the `glibc` source and enable Blowfish.  For the password hashing, it is not clear whether `crypt()` runs Blowfish once or several times; nor is it clear how the salt perturbs the encryption/hashing.  If no-one answers from their own knowledge, it will be time to go to the source.

Comment: OpenSSL has `DES_fcrypt`, which is a fast version of the Unix `crypt(3)` command using DES. I don't know if there's a Blowfish equivalent. See the [des(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/des.html) docs.

Comment: musl-libc includes blowfish (http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/crypt/crypt_blowfish.c) , makes a fairly small static binary (sometimes even smaller than dynamically built glibc binaries) and it can coexist with your existing libc and build tools... definitely less overhead than including openssl and less licensing issues